# JSF Read Text File

Tags: java, javabeans

I've been googling all over the place for information on how to display content from a .txt file onto a web page using JSF with no success.

From what I think/guess, the basic jsf form would be something like

```
<h:outputText value="#{beanName.printTextFileMethod}"/>
```

or something.

Help on how to set up bean appreciated. I tried playing with InputStream/BufferedStream, having a lot of problem just trying to get rid of the red lines in codes. Also I'm absolutely horrid at defining relative path. And absolute path doesn't seem to work with inputstream?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you read in a file into a String?

Comment: You have a Java problem, not from JSF. Check [Best way to read a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4716503/1065197) to solve your riddles about working with text files.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class TextFileBean{   
        String completeMessage = null;
         public TextFileBean(){
          try{
           //read data from the text file
           java.io.BufferedReader in=
              new java.io.BufferedReader(
                new java.io.InputStreamReader(
                  TextFileBean.this.getClass().
                   getResourceAsStream("txtFile.txt"
               )));
 System.out.println("in :" +in);
           readData(in);
           in.close();
           } catch (java.io.IOException IOex) {
             System.out.println("IO Error :" +IOex);
           }
         }    

        private void readData(BufferedReader br) {
        // dosomethig
        String line = null;     
        StringBuffer appendMessage = null;
        try {
            appendMessage = new StringBuffer(16384);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                appendMessage.append(line);
                appendMessage.append('\n');
            }
            if (appendMessage != null) {
                completeMessage = appendMessage.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public String printTextFileMethod()
    {

        System.out.println("completeMessage:: "+ completeMessage);         
            return completeMessage;
     }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I finally see a clean code on my page without any red lines. I'm assuming with your code, you call it by
    <h:outputText value="#{textFileBean.readData} />
While it launches with no problem. There is no data being displayed. Should I put the file somewhere specific?

Comment: Not yet, sorry. Still a blank page on my end.

Comment: if file path found then it will eneter readData method block,otherwise it will throws FileNotFoundException. are u getting any exception?

Comment: No exceptions, everything seems to run fine. I placed another outputText with the value of "Whee" and it prints that, just no data from text file.

Comment: try to print log info into while block

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by print log info :(

Comment: Oh yes, I put a System.out.print(line) in while loop, nothing from text file shows up also. Also a System.out.print("asdhfkjahfd"), which also didn't print.

Comment: before calling readData() check BufferedReader  in is null or not

Comment: I placed a if statement which check if BuffedReader in is null or not before calling readData, but the System.out.print(), isn't printing anything too.

Comment: which bean method are u calling? call printTextFileMethod() method

Comment: for checking if method is calling ,print any text into readData method. It is private method.

Comment: Yahh, I tried to print anything on it. Also tried changing it to public. nothing prints

Comment: call printTextFileMethod method with print something.check your faces-config file managed bean scope is set session or application

Comment: Hm, first thing I did was set the scope to session. I use netbeans, so  faces-config doesn't appear to be created with creation of new projects. And calling printTextFileMethod, with string "Print something" also no work

Comment: is printTextFileMethod method called from bean?

Comment: check constructor  calling and readData method , flow step by step where it is calling or not.

Comment: Hmm, I just realized, it probably wasn't called...
Cause when you try to call the bean from jsf, the option to select the given methods from textFileBean isn't showing up.

Comment: I tried various things, it says I'm unable to instantiate TextFileBean, so I removed the catchIO instructor from the constructor catch block. And now it says, unable to find method readData